# Ruby watir page object implementation

Tags: ruby, watir, pageobjects

Trying to add a variable with `webelement` to a method, then use this method with `.click`

```
def login_button
@browser.element(:class => /button radius button-demo/)
  end

login_button.click
```

But, keep getting the same error:

> undefined local variable or method `login_button' for
>   PageObjects:Class (NameError)

but if you do this way:

```
 @browser.element(:class => /button radius button-demo/).click
```

without adding it to a method, everything works fine.

Official Watir guide provides option with adding variable to a method, but for somereason I can't make it work :(

Comment: you can use cheezy page object. And then you can create the element as below `button(:login_button, :class => /button radius button-demo/)`. To click the element `login_button.click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple code snippet using cheezy page object.

```
require 'page-object'
class Login_Page
   include PageObject
   text_field(:user_name, css: "[name='username']")
   text_field(:password, css: "[name='password']")
   button(:sign_in, css: "button[type='submit']")

   def click_on_sign_in
       sign_in # default method is click for button element
       # if you want to call click method
       sign_in.wait_until(100, &:present?).click
       # clicking using fire event
       sign_in.wait_until(100, &:present?).fire_event :onclick
   end
end
```

Refer to [cheezy documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/PageObject) for more information.

Comment: Okay, this is getting weird, I made everything according to the cheezy guide, and your example, and now I'm having another problem, Ruby does not actually see "sign_in" variable, I tried to make a method in class, tried to do it out of class, same thing "sign_in", Ruby can't see it.

Comment: Do  you want to call the `click_on_sign_in` method or access the element present in `Login_Page class?

Comment: Found what was the problem, RubyMine IDE does not recognise the names that you assign to your buttons/text fields. Everything works perfectly, thanks!